# Code in try block is not running for the second time

Tags: java, static, try-catch

I have a `static` method:

```
 public static String languageDetection(String input) {
    String lang = null;
    try {
        DetectorFactory.loadProfile(PROFILE_PATH);
        Detector detector = DetectorFactory.create();
        detector.append(input);
        lang = detector.detect();
    } catch (LangDetectException e) {
        // LoggerSimple.warn("LangDetectException" + e.getMessage(), LanguageDetection.class);
    }
    if (lang!=null)
    return language.valueOf(lang).getLanguage();
    else return lang;
}
```

and I call it twice in my main method:

```
    LanguageDetection.languageDetection("hellooooooooo");
    LanguageDetection.languageDetection("this is an english text");
```

but the second time when in enter `languageDetection` method it does not enter the `try` block.

Does any body know why?

Comment: How do you know that the code inside the block is not executed twice? Have you tried with a debugger?

Comment: How do you know that the `try` block is not entered?

Comment: yes,i debug it with print

Comment: update the code with your debugger line...

Comment: There's no reason this should not *enter* the `try` block.  Whether it stays there long enough to execute the whole block is a different issue.  What behaviour are you seeing?

Comment: it ignore try block and return null value for lang

Comment: You should try it with a debugger setting a breakpoint at the first line. OR it is possible that you did not compile your code and you are trying to run an older version.

Comment: The code _will_ "enter" the try block. You probably just have put your debug print after an exception has occured.

Comment: it runs DetectorFactory.loadProfile(PROFILE_PATH); line and then exit try block and continue,is this problem for loding profiles twice?

Comment: it was becouse of DetectorFactory.loadProfile(PROFILE_PATH); infact it enter try block but after this line when profile is exist it throws an exception and exit try block.

Answer (score 0):

Line DetectorFactory.loadProfile(PROFILE_PATH); seems suspicious maybe it throws an exception if it is called twice, then it would seem like that try not executed

Comment: yes after this line it exit try block and continue from if (lang!=null) line

Comment: SO there is your answer. It executes try block twice, but on second time throws an exception. Uncomment: 
 
LoggerSimple.warn("LangDetectException" + e.getMessage(), LanguageDetection.class);
 
and at least you will see exception.

And do not write empty catch block ever again. It is such a bad practice.